# contour lines from the edge of a map don't show up on basemap

Tags: matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-basemap

I'm drawing several contour lines over a basemap projection as shown in the following figure:[image].

There are 3 contours that are not drawn completely (**in Oregon, Washington and California**) and seems like there is this line that has cut all 3 of them in the same latitude. I'm not sure how to solve this problem.
I added the number of interpolation points, didn't help. changed the ll and ur points to include more area didn't help.

The code is below (**not reproducible** but might help):

```
def visualise_bigaus(mus, sigmas, corxys , output_type='pdf', **kwargs):





    lllat = 24.396308
    lllon = -124.848974
    urlat =  49.384358
    urlon = -66.885444

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2.5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=False)
    m = Basemap(llcrnrlat=lllat,
    urcrnrlat=urlat,
    llcrnrlon=lllon,
    urcrnrlon=urlon,
    resolution='i', projection='cyl')

    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color = 'white')
    #m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.2)
    m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.2)
    m.drawstates(linewidth=0.2, color='lightgray')
    #m.fillcontinents(color='white', lake_color='#0000ff', zorder=2)
    #m.drawrivers(color='#0000ff')
    m.drawlsmask(land_color='gray',ocean_color="#b0c4de", lakes=True)
    lllon, lllat = m(lllon, lllat)
    urlon, urlat = m(urlon, urlat)
    mlon, mlat = m(*(mus[:,1], mus[:,0]))
    numcols, numrows = 1000, 1000
    X = np.linspace(mlon.min(), urlon, numcols)
    Y = np.linspace(lllat, urlat, numrows)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    m.scatter(mlon, mlat, s=0.2, c='red')
    shp_info = m.readshapefile('./data/us_states_st99/st99_d00','states',drawbounds=True, zorder=0)
    printed_names = []
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False) 
    for spine in ax.spines.itervalues(): 
        spine.set_visible(False) 


    for k in xrange(mus.shape[0]):
        #here x is longitude and y is latitude
        #apply softplus to sigmas (to make them positive)
        sigmax=np.log(1 + np.exp(sigmas[k][1]))
        sigmay=np.log(1 + np.exp(sigmas[k][0]))
        mux=mlon[k]
        muy=mlat[k]
        corxy = corxys[k]
        #apply the soft sign
        corxy = corxy / (1 + np.abs(corxy))
        #now given corxy find sigmaxy
        sigmaxy = corxy * sigmax * sigmay

        #corxy = 1.0 / (1 + np.abs(sigmaxy))
        Z = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, sigmax=sigmax, sigmay=sigmay, mux=mux, muy=muy, sigmaxy=sigmaxy)

        #Z = maskoceans(X, Y, Z)


        con = m.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[0.02], linewidths=0.5, colors='darkorange', antialiased=True)
        '''
        num_levels = len(con.collections)
        if num_levels > 1:
            for i in range(0, num_levels):
                if i != (num_levels-1):
                    con.collections[i].set_visible(False)
        '''
        contour_labels = False
        if contour_labels:
            plt.clabel(con, [con.levels[-1]], inline=True, fontsize=10)

    '''
    world_shp_info = m.readshapefile('./data/CNTR_2014_10M_SH/Data/CNTR_RG_10M_2014','world',drawbounds=False, zorder=100)
    for shapedict,state in zip(m.world_info, m.world):
        if shapedict['CNTR_ID'] not in ['CA', 'MX']: continue
        poly = MplPolygon(state,facecolor='gray',edgecolor='gray')
        ax.add_patch(poly)
    '''                
    if iter:
        iter = str(iter).zfill(3)
    else:
        iter = ''
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('./maps/video/gaus_' + iter  + '.' + output_type, frameon=False, dpi=200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the meshgrid not covering the complete map. The meshgrid simply doesn't have any points at the positions where you want to draw the gaussian contour line.

An example to reproduce this behaviour is the following, where the meshgrid in x directio starts at `-1`, such that points lower than that are not drawn.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot([-2,2],[-2,-2], alpha=0)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,2),np.linspace(-2,2))
Z = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, sigmax=1., sigmay=1., mux=0.1, muy=0.1, sigmaxy=0)
con = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[Z.max()/3, Z.max()/2., Z.max()*0.8],colors='darkorange')
plt.show()
```

[image]

A similar problem occurs in the code from the question.
While in Y direction, you use the complete map, `Y = np.linspace(lllat, urlat, numrows)`, in X direction you restrict the mesh to start at `mlon.min()`,

```
X = np.linspace(mlon.min(), urlon, numcols)
```

The solution would of course be not to start the mesh in Portland, but somewhere in the ocean, i.e. at the edge of the shown map.